# How do i terminate the program if condition evaluate to true

Tags: apex

```
if(!String.isBlank(dt)){
    Date d = Date.parse(dt);
    if(d< date.today()-30){            
        break;// If this condition is true i want to exit the program throwing error message.
    }
}
```

I tried to insert **break** but i got the error **Break statement must be in loop**

Comment: Please update the question and provide the rest of the code

Comment: Use `return;` to end the program. Similar question -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14847524/how-to-exit-an-apex-function

Comment: use `throw new MyException(..)`

Answer (score 1):

break statement is only used on loops like for ,while,do while ... 
There is no concept of loop in if .
If you use if when the condition is true we will go inside to if block and execute the code or else we will come outside of the if statement .